# How do I package an Sqlite3 database with my Python3 fbs package?

Tags: python, macos, sqlite, pyqt5, fbs

I am building a Python app using FBS, but part of it relies on an SQLite3 database. I have code to create this database if it doesn't find this, using a try-catch block.

When I try to run it after compiling, it not only can not find the preexisting SQLite3 file, but also won't create it. It does not display any error messages.

I have tried creating the file if it doesn't exist using this code:

```
try:
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
except:
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        # Try and make the .config directory
        try:
            os.makedirs(".config")
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise

        # Create the datastore, and close it
        f = open(path, "w+")
        f.close()
        # And try connect to database again
        return self.__connect(path)
    else:
        print(f"No database exists, and could not create one.\nPlease create file in app directory called: {path}\nThen restart application.")
        raise
```

The code works find in dev, but as soon as I compile it to a Mac app, it refuses to find or create the database.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. If anyone has a similar issue please use the builtin `appctxt.get_resource(file_path)` method.